# One "list" below another inside a ScrollView

Tags: android

I would like to reproduce this layout :

[image: Exemple]

The blue lists are not scrollable, but the red panel (probably LinearLayout) is.

I already tried two ListView but I don't think it is the good way to do this, it doesn't work.

I read an article that advised to add multiple items to a LinearLayout. But in doing so, how to handle events on a single item, or use a BaseAdapter ?

I know I'm a little vague, but I'm having a little trouble explaining what I really want, I started Android development a few days ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it uses any ListView.

You can probably create something like this by having the red panel be a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout that's inside a ScrollView, so that it scrolls.

Then the blue "list" is probably not a ListView if it doesn't scroll. I guess it's just a bunch of regular views. So, something like this (pseudo code)

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
     <whatever layout for the green cell>
     <include layout="blue_cell>
     <include layout="blue_cell>
     ...
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And then you just create a layout for your blue cell, see info here: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

If you have a variable number of blue cells, you can just have the `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` in XML, and inflate the blue cells layout programatically and add them to the `LinearLayout`